# Display only one element at a time in react with .map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So basically I'm creating a quiz component, and I need to loop through all the questions, but display only one question at a time, and after the question is answered, display another one.

How could I do that? I would normally use for loop, but it is not recommended, how can I achieve the same outcome with .map(), or any other function?

This is basically what I want to happen:

```
    for(let i = 0; i < quiz.questions.length(); i++) {
        return (
            <Content>
                <View style={styles.gutter}>
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <View style={styles.content}>
                            <Text>{quiz.questions[i].question}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <Button
                            primary
                            label={quiz.answers.option1}
                            onPress={() => {
                                quiz.answers.option1 === quiz.questions[i].rightAnswer
                                    ? continue // would continue work here as expected?
                                    : console.log("Wrong");
                            }}></Button>
                        <Button
                            primary
                            label={quiz.answers.option2}
                            onPress={() => {
                                quiz.answers.option2 === quiz.questions[i].rightAnswer
                                    ? continue // would continue work here as expected?
                                    : console.log("Wrong");
                            }}></Button>
                        <Button
                            primary
                            label={quiz.answers.option3}
                            onPress={() => {
                                quiz.answers.option3 === quiz.questions[i].rightAnswer
                                    ? continue // would continue work here as expected?
                                    : console.log("Wrong");
                            }}></Button>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Content>
        );
    }
```

Comment: your example is wrong since the for loop `returns` in the first iteration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create a functional component with useState hook:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
function Quiz() {
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(1);

    const current = quiz.questions[index];
    return (
        <Content>
            <View style={styles.gutter}>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.content}>
                        <Text>{current.question}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <Button
                        primary
                        label={quiz.answers.option1}
                        onPress={() => {
                            if (quiz.answers.option1 === current.rightAnswer) {
                                setIndex(index + 1);
                            } else {
                                console.log('Wrong');
                            }
                        }}
                    />
                    <Button
                        primary
                        label={quiz.answers.option2}
                        onPress={() => {
                            if (quiz.answers.option2 === current.rightAnswer) {
                                setIndex(index + 1);
                            } else {
                                console.log('Wrong');
                            }
                        }}
                    />
                    <Button
                        primary
                        label={quiz.answers.option3}
                        onPress={() => {
                            if (quiz.answers.option3 === current.rightAnswer) {
                                setIndex(index + 1);
                            } else {
                                console.log('Wrong');
                            }
                        }}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        </Content>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only one answer you should write a code like this:
I think you wanted to load one item already and you got `undefined` error message, so that's why you are asking your question
Let's assume you are getting your data via props of redux(it can be anything like regular state)

```
Render(){
<div>
{this.props.mydata && 
 this.props.mydata.quiz[0] &&
  this.props.mydata.quiz[0].question
}
</div>
  }
```

This code checks your data, whenever the data loaded you can use it and you won't get any error. And you need to make it whenever your player answered right it goes +1 in array.

I hope you got the idea and works for you